# How to determine most impactful input variables in a dataset?

Tags: python, correlation

I have a neural network program that is designed to take in input variables and output variables, and use forecasted data to predict what the output variables should be based on the forecasted data. After running this program, I will have an output of an output vector. Lets say for example, my input matrix is 100 rows and 10 columns and my output matrix is a vector with 100 values. How do I determine which of my 10 variables (columns) had the most impact on my output?

I've done a correlation analysis between each of my variables (columns) and my output and created a list of the highest correlation between each variable and output, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: so where is your code snippet? please, read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can't really enter my code without entering some proprietary information. Its just an input matrix of 100 rows and 10 columns, and an output vector of 100 values. It can be any which numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to know is *model selection*, and it's not as simple as studiying the correlation of your features to your target. For an in-depth, well explained look at model selection, I'd recommend you read chapter 7 of [The Elements Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf). If what you're looking for is how to *explain your network*, then you're in for a treat as well and I'd recommend reading [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/interpretability-of-deep-learning-models-9f52e54d72ab) article for starters, though I won't go into the matter myself.

#### Naive approaches to model selection:

There a number of ways to do this.
The naïve way is to estimate *all possible models*, so every combination of features. Since you have 10 features, it's computationally unfeasible.

Another way is to take a variable you think is a good predictor and train to model only on that variable. Compute the error on the training data. Take another variable at random, retrain the model and recompute the error on the training data. If it drops the error, keep the variable. Otherwise discard it. Keep going for all features.

A third approach is the opposite. Start with training the model on all features and sequentially drop variables (a less naïve approach would be to drop variables you intuitively think have little explanatory power), compute the error on training data and compare to know if you keep the feature or not.

There are million ways of going about this. I've exposed three of the simplest, but again, you can go really deeply into this subject and find all kinds of different information (which is why I highly recommend you read that chapter :) ).

Comment: Thanks for your input - no, I am not asking about model selection or how to explain a neural network, I am asking about simply determining which variables have the most impact on an outcome. Maybe I am being naive I can't talk about variable impact without talking about how I got to that outcome?

Comment: In the case of Neural Networks, talking about input impact on predictions is what is known as explaining models. In [this question](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_understand_the_relationships_between_inputs_and_outputs_in_neural_network_prediction_model) the guy asks a very similar question to yours; look at the amount of different methods there are to do that! (Good thing is that you can use existing libraries to achieve that).

Comment: The reason I don't believe in correlation analysis in the case of Deep Learning is the structure of the model. A variable may be uncorrelated to the output, but have a high weight assigned to one of the hidden neurons thus impacting other variables which in turn themselves have a high impact on the outcome. (Although I leave open the possibility of being wrong, since I haven't studied the matter enough yet).

Comment: Wait, I've just re-read your question and am very confused. What do you mean by  "I will have an output of: input matrix (of variables) and an output vector" ? Are you trying to predict inputs as well as outputs?..

Comment: My fault, no the inputs are just inputs and the only output is the output vector which is equal to the amount of rows in the input matrix. The link you sent is helpful, thanks! Which existing packages are you referring to?

Comment: Take a look at the article I linked to in my answer. It's a dive into the `shap` python package which implements DeepSHAP procedure for neural network interpretability. EOD, when it comes to ML in Python I find you rarely have to make tools yourself. I'm sure even if DeepSHAP isn't what you're looking for you'll find plenty of other open source libraries given how important of a subject it is for the generalization of ML use in some industries - notably, the financial sector.